# Click event in select2 tag with a link

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2 in tag mode. My item text is a link, e.g.:

```
<a href='url'>tag1</a>.
```

select2 seems to be swallowing the click event on the tag (selected choice) so I cannot navigate to the link.

Any ideas on how to get the link to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select2 disables click events by default and for the moment, you must use a workaround to achieve the desired results. Here's an example of how I accomplished this, thanks to the resources below. This won't work if you don't re-instantiate the variable with the return value of .data('select2')

First, add a class to your links:

```
<a href="#" class="detail-link">hello</a>
```

Then you have to listen to the onSelect event of Select2

```
    var search = $("#searchBox");
    search.select2({
        placeholder: "Search...",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        maximumSelectionSize: 1,
        escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
        ajax: {     blah blah blah       },
        formatResult: window.App.formatFunction
    });


    search= search.data('select2');

    search.onSelect = (function(fn) {
        return function(data, options) {
            var target;

            if (options != null) {
                target = $(options.target);
            }

            if (target && target.hasClass('detail-link')) {
                window.location = target.attr('href');
            } else {
                return fn.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    })(search.onSelect);
```

This question/answer/JFiddle helped me out but its important to note the .data('select2') line

EDIT: forgot the resource -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637696

Comment: I was actually referring to the displayed selected tags (not in search result dropdown). But the above works by using the selectChoice instead of onSelect. E.g. "search.selectChoice = (func..."

Comment: This does not work on latest select2 versions (4.1.0)

Answer (score 7):

I use [select2-selecting event](http://select2.github.io/select2/):

```
var $q = $('#select2input');
$q.select2({
    // your settings
});

$q.on('select2-selecting', function(e){
    window.location = e.choice.url;
});
```

My AJAX payload looks like this:

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "id": "1",
            "text": "Foo",
            "url": "/foo"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "text": "Bar",
            "url": "/bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In version 4+ the select event is `select2:selecting`. From [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18615267/997596)