# redirect URL when Select2 option clicked

Tags: html, jquery-select2

I have a select menu where users can filter jobs. I wanted to add a "list all" option, that should just redirect them to the index page, because that lists everything. But I can't do that because I'm using

```
onchange="form.submit()"
```

and this is the result I get if I put "index.php" in the value like this:

```
<option value="index.php">list all</option>

mypage/index.php?slct=index.php
```

but I should get this:

```
mypage/index.php
```

Tried to leave the value empty, but that doesn't work on live server:

```
index.php?slct=
```

How should I do this? I'm using [select2](https://select2.org/) js and the `<a href>` doesn't work with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click event in select2 tag with a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349399/click-event-in-select2-tag-with-a-link)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jogaco/0h8tc6Lj/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15636302/104380

Comment: https://jsbin.com/kevutavuke/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: 2-minutes Google-search provided me with the above information that may help you.

Comment: Yes it really does, but all of these uses + words to put the links to. Is it possible to add the link to the "google" itself or I must add a "preview" word to it? https://jsbin.com/kevutavuke/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I don't understand why you've said *"`<a href>` doesn't work"* what does this mean "not work" means? in what why is it not working? you shown in your code that you don't have an href link in your option... so how can it work if you don't even have a link?

Comment: I've tried with href but that didn't show up, that's why I thought it didn't work. Now I can see it does, but do I need to add another word to it?

Comment: doesn't Select2 allows customize the options template?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36360910/104380

Comment: Tried all of the links but none of them did anything. Nothing's changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've manged to hack a workable demo after reading [the docs](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events)

```js
var data = [
  {
      "id": "1",
      "text": "See all",
      "url": "https://google.com"
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "text": "option 2"
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "text": "option 3"
  }
];

$("select").select2({
   placeholder: 'please choose',
   data: data
});

$("select").on('select2:select', function(e){
   if( e.params.data.url )
        window.location = e.params.data.url;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select style="width: 50%">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

[empty option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25410119/104380) is used for the placeholder to be shown

Comment: I literally copy-paste your code, and it's working on fiddle, but not doing anything on my localhost. I select the 'see all' option and nothing happens.

Comment: place a `console.log(e.params.data)` in the `select2:select` callback and see what's going on when you select it

Comment: Also make sure to have an empty `<option></option>` inside your `<select>` element, so the first option won't be chosen by default. if it is, you won't be able to click it, since it's already chosen

Comment: I have a ```onchange="form.submit();"``` in  ```<select>``` and it doesn't even log if I don't remove that. After the remove (but I'll need it so I cant remove.), I get this in my console, but still doesn't load a new page https://imgur.com/EIWlu6t

Comment: I don't see `url` property in the screenshot so of course it wouldn't work. how can it work without it? why didn't you set `url` property like in my answer? it's all based around that

Comment: I copy pasted your code. There is the ```"url": "https://google.com"```

Comment: There is no `url` in the screenshot you places in the comment some 2 hours ago..