# Codeigniter 4 Select2 is not showing links

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, jquery-select2

I'm working with CodeIgniter for and Select2 to populate search results. It is working well but the populated data doesn't have a link. Can someone point me to the right direction?
Here is my controller:

```
public function ajaxSearch()
{
    helper(['form', 'url']);

    $data = [];

    $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table('courses');   

    $query = $builder->like('courseName', $this->request->getVar('q'))
                ->select('courseID, courseName as text')
                ->limit(10)->get();
    $data = $query->getResult();
     
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Here my view:

```js
<script>
   
    $('.search').select2({
        placeholder: '--- What do you want to learn today? ---',
        ajax: {
            url: '<?php echo base_url('Home/ajaxSearch');?>',

            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function(data){
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<select class="search form-control" name="search"></select>
```

I am usiing CDN to get the JS and css files.
I need it to have a link on the results to go to the course id `href="../course/<?php echo $course->courseID;?>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click event in select2 tag with a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349399/click-event-in-select2-tag-with-a-link)

Comment: '<?php echo base_url("Home/ajaxSearch");?>' change your syntax